# One video, four overlays, X options for each overlay, how many total possible videos generated?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a video and want to overlay four total images on top of it (in different corners, say).

Each overlay has X number of options though. So how would one determine the total number of unique generated videos?

Overlay 1: 5 options

Overlay 2: 6 options

Overlay 3: 3 options

Overlay 4: 3 options

Note: one of each option must be selected. So there will always be at least 4 different overlays.

I think factorials are involved here but am not sure how exactly to determine the answer. If I had to guess, it would be:

5! * 6! * 3! * 3!

But I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how many simultaneous options for each overlay you can have.  I don't see it involving factorials, though.

**Edit:** You stated that you needed at least one option from each overlay.

The first overlay has $5$ options, which can each be on or off, so that's $2^5 = 32$ possibilities, minus the one that is all off, so $31$ total possibilities for the first overlay.

For the second, third, and fourth overlay, similarly, you have $63, 7,$ and $7$ possibilities, respectively.

So ... $31 \times 63 \times 7 \times 7 = 95,697 $ possible videos.

Comment: I added a note clarifying that one option from each overlay will always be displayed. Does that change the answer?

Comment: At least one, or exactly one?

Comment: Oh sorry. At least one from each. This question could probably be simplified, because it's very similar to dice rolls: imagine a 5-sided die, a 6-sided die and two 3-sided dice. Order/independence matters, so they are not all rolled in a jar but rather independently. What is the unique total # of possible outcomes?

Comment: Edited my answer.